# What does it cost to repair a Canon EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III Lens?

Tags: canon, repair, canon-ef, canon-350d

I recently loaned my Zoom lens out and it came back damaged. What would it cost to repair it? Should I just get a new lens?

[image: Side damage][image: Top ring damage]

Comment: We can't answer this. We don't know what's wrong with it and probably are not in a position to say, e.g. parts and labour. Speak to an authorised Canon service centre and get a quote.

Comment: I attached photos to show what is wrong with it.

Comment: Damaged front element? UK repair cost (from www.fixatiouk.com) is £35-£200 + parts. You should really get a quote from repair centre, as Crazy D suggested, but Iit may be BER (Beyond Economical Repair).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should get a new lens. The 75-300 is almost unquestionably the worst lens made by Canon, so spending *any* money on it is a bad investment.

Answer (score 3):

> What would it cost to repair it? Should I just get a new lens?

I don't know how much it'll cost to repair, but it's hard to imagine that it'll be less than the cost to replace it. Amazon has a [factory-refurbished EF 75-300mm f/4-5.6 III](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016SN92V0) for under $100.